# how to embedded start timing in yotube video using youtube API's

Tags: jsp

guys i need to start a youtube video from a specific time which have to done through using youtube API's . can i pass parameters using iframe tag .

rel="0" frameborder="0" start= allowfullscreen>

Comment: Share with us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

With the total number of seconds into the video where I want it to start, along with ?start=, I’ll replace the ?rel=0 code. So, my embed code will look like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/i_mKY2CQ9Kk?start=399" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to test on localhost, add http or https in src attribute like this,

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/i_mKY2CQ9Kk?start=399" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```